# Filtering out files in profile results

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to filter out some files from collecting CPU profiles in or just filter them out in CPU profile results?
That's what I'm talking about (http://grab.by/so7y):
[image]
There's no way to filter the results by filename.
I tried to find it in Profiles, in Timeline, in Google Web Trace Framework.
And there is no such thing as far as I see.
Or maybe it's time to make that feature?
I think every developer needs it as far as he doesn't want to profile frameworks that he uses.
I found "black box" feature in FF 27 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger#Black_box_a_source) but that is for debugging only.

Comment: I was looking for the same feature, and as you, found it did not exist. I was able to get better results using the [console API](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consoleprofilelabel), specifically `console.profile() and console.profileEnd()`

Comment: console API is a great hint, but it does not work for me, because I try to figure out which of my external scripts (from CMS Plugins etc.) take how much time.
Does somebody know a tool where this can be done with?

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer to "how Filtering out files in PROFILE RESULTS" but just "how filtering out files in Chrome", which should give you the infos you need:

Just use the Chrome developer tab "Timeline" instead of "Profiles", and have the checkbox for "JS Profile" activated. After you measured something, you can go to tab "Aggregated Details" and select

"View Costly Functions" and "Group by URL".

You then have a list of the time the functions from specific scripts needed:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be out of date. I no longer see a Timeline tab, but Memory next to Performance. It has an Allocation Timeline option, but I don't think that's quite the same thing. Do you have an updated suggestion?

Comment: This answer is definetly outdated