# Profile javascript performance of my scripts with chrome or another tool by file

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

I try to figure out which script on my page takes a lot of javascript load (it`s a wordpress page with a lot of plugins).

I`m using the chrome developer tools to profile the JavaScript performance:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

After profiling, I get a list with a lot of functions and the filenames they are in.

But I`m missing a filter, which filters by file, so that I can see which script from which files do have a big impact to the javascript execution time.

Am I missing something, or is this not possible? Are there tools (e.g. chrome extensions) which are able to do so?

Comment: It's possible your question is duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243896/filtering-out-files-in-profile-results). So try to use console API.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, it a duplicate. Console API does not really work for me, because those scripts are scripts from plugins. I will continue questioning in the other thread.